# How to fix “403 forbidden” redirect issue happens while adding shopping cart price rule condition in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, ajax

My task is to add new shopping cart price rule in magento admin section. I have added rule information, then **I need to add conditions for that rule .When I change the condition select box option, it's redirected to dashboard**.

In the chrome console it shows 403 forbidden error in the ajax url.

Somebody told me to disable mod_security. I have written the below code in .htaceess file, but still the problem continues.

.htacesss :

SecFilterEngine Off

SecFilterScanPOST Off

I am using Magento version. 1.9.3.8

How to fix this please help me.

Comment: are you getting any error log ? in system.log or exception.log ?

Comment: no i didn't got any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified a single line in rule.js file. (path : /var/www/vhosts/site.com/htdocsnew/js/mage/adminhtml/rule.js)

Old

{form_key: FORM_KEY, type:new_type.replace('/','-'), id: new_id }

New

{form_key: FORM_KEY, type:new_type.replace('/','-'), id:"'"+new_id+"'" }